# How to launch built in efi shell?

Tags: boot, bios, grub, uefi, efi

I have a Lenovo ThinkCenter with American MegaTrends (AMI) UEFI with UEFI shell  v2.0.31 I think. From clover bootloader, there is an option to launch the shell and I'm able to enter it. However, from the blue setup (which comes after F12), I couldn't find a way to enter this shell. I can bring up the small hdd selection menu using F12 (and thereafter the blue setup) but there is no way to run shell from there either. How can run this shell? (Side question, how to launch this same shell from grub EFI just like clover does?)?

Comment: I'm interested in a possible answer, because I too have a laptop with an American Megatrends BIOS/UEFI that won't boot anymore after an aborted Windows Update, and even though the Power LED comes on when I press the Power button, the screen remains black, so if someone knows how to wake the darn thing up, I'd like to know! (Rant's over. As you were... :-D)

Comment: I may have bad news and as much as I'd like all dead computers to stop working, if you cannot even enter Setup then this question is not for you .. :(

Comment: I was afraid you'd say that... :-( I'm going to call the mortuary then, and make sure the poor little thing gets a proper funeral. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Didier  Sorry I meant as much as I'd love all dead computers to **start** working!!

Comment: Apparently American megatreds is AMI, check this maybe-- https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/bios-flash-with-serial-port.427706/  Have you tried smashing your keyboard on boot? I usually bang F1, F2, F10, F12 and Del on all computers. You have 10 fingers and borrow a friends' and you should have something in a few reboots. Also this- http://www.murga-linux.com/puppy/viewtopic.php?p=543911

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to check up on all that, because there's a lot to read! :-) I had searched the forum at Tom's Hardware, but only recent entries. Thanks for the info, and I hope you solve your own problem.